# Identify positions at which a vector of cumulative sums exceeds

Tags: r

I have a named vector of cumulated sums:

```
x <- sort(runif(20, 1, 10), decreasing = T)
names(x) <- LETTERS[1:20] 
cumsums <- cumsum(x)

head(cumsums)
        A         B         C         D         E         F 
9.902633 19.240766 28.531703 37.537920 46.065978 54.380480
```

How can i identify the positions at which the first value of `cumsums` exceeds a defined threshold (e.g. 25,50,75, 90)?

Comment: something like `which.max(cumsums > 25)`

Comment: @jogo, not if the underlying vector could contain negative values

Comment: Id accept the which.max solution. thank you

Comment: @jogo, try it with `x <- c(1:10, -4:(-8))` if you want to know the first element that's > 5.

Comment: @nouse, just one thing you need to keep in mind: if there is no element in your cumsums vector that satifies the inequality, `which.max` will return 1 (because all elements are FALSE and it will give you the index of the first maximum which, in such a case, would be a FALSE value)

Comment: @docendodiscimus You are right. I was assuming monotonic `cumsums` (which is identical with only positive values in `x`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single threshold at a time, the following should work:

```
which(cumsums > 25)[1]
```

Unlike the `which.max` solution, it will return `NA` if there are no elements of `cumsums` greater than the threshold.

Of course, if your vector is very large or you need to look for multiple thresholds simultaneously, this may not be the most efficient solution.